# LOOPING THROUGH LOCATIONS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following query that I have gets the items, itemid, category, quantity, quantityadded, quantity total and their can be same items in different locations.

```
SELECT
    it.itemno,
    it.item,
    c.category,
    q.owned,
    q.added,
    (q.owned + q.added) AS total,
    (q.owned * it.cost) AS Tcost
FROM item it
INNER JOIN phiq     q  ON it.itemlid = q.itemlid
INNER JOIN category c  ON c.catid = it.catid
WHERE q.locationid = '12653'
  AND q.qdate LIKE '%2013%'
```

Since there will be three different locations, i will need to run this query 3 different times with just the different location.There are also years this is for 2013 but I should be able ot run this also for 2012 to compare again for 3 locations And then for each item i need the total for each location for example:

ITEMID ITEM  category Loc1owned Loc1added loc1total loc2owned loc2total loc3owned loc3added loc3total TOTAL (loc1toal+loc2total+loc3total)

Since the previous loc would all be for 2013 I would have the same (loc1owned, loc1total,loc2owned)..... for 2012 year as well and this will all be 1 row for each item and so on.

My question is how would I do that in SQL. is there a loop....iterations...Im fairly new to this so help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you attach some screen shots of the tables that your query is using? and the result that you wish to achieve? this will help to answer to you more efficiently.

Comment: It looks like you're storing your date in a string column. That's a big no-no. Use a Date, DateTime, or DateTime2 type instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
SELECT  q.locationid, it.itemno,it.item,c.category,q.owned
        ,q.added,(q.owned+q.added) as total, (q.owned*it.cost) as Tcost 
FROM    item it
        INNER JOIN phiq q on it.itemlid= q.itemlid
        INNER JOIN category c on c.catid=it.catid
WHERE   q.locationid IN ('12653', 'anotherlocation', 'nextlocation')
        AND (q.qdate LIKE '%2013%')
GROUP BY    q.locationid, it.itemno,it.item,c.category,q.owned,q.added
            ,(q.owned+q.added), (q.owned*it.cost)
```

I cannot do the year unless I know what is the data type for it (and content).